# How can I place "Last Name" label below the input field of last name?

Tags: html, css

```html
<h4>Full name</h4>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fn" />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" /><br />
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<label for="lname">Last Name</label>
```

In the above code the label for first name and last name appears side by side, how to place the label for last name just below the input field of last name, without using `pre` tag

Comment: Can you change the markup? You have to change the markup, if only to correct the `for` attributes.

Comment: @d-h-e I tried it but for "block" the "last name" label is appearing below "first name label"

Comment: @MrLister instead of for what else can I use?

Comment: The for attributes are supposed to point to the inputs' id values, not to their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple **Flexbox** which is kind of professional work and if you did not know much about **Flexbox**. Here is a simple tutorial on [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.maindiv{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center
}

.inputdiv{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<h4>Full name</h4>

<div class="maindiv">
  <div class='inputdiv'>
    <input type = "text" name="fname" id = "fn" />
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class='inputdiv'>
    <input type = "text" name="lname" id = "ln" />
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox can clean make it easier to do layouts.

```css
.groupings {
  display: flex;
}

.groupings label,
.groupings label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Full name</legend>
  <div class="groupings">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fn" />
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" />
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  position: relative;
  top: -3em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<label>First Name <input type="text" name="fname" id="fn" /></label>
  <label>Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" id="ln" /></label>
```